# Windows 7 x64 hard disk light continuously flashing

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

My Windows 7 x64 hard disk light is continuously flashing. I had a look in the task manager but i cant find any programs which is over using the memory or cpu. I was wondering if there are any good free / open source tools to monitor hard disk activity which can tell me which program is causing the IO.

Comment: Try disabling your CD/DVD drive in Device Manager.

Answer (score 3):

sysinternals [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) should do the trick - it lets monitors almost everything that a process does - file write, registry, and file operations

Comment: the sysinternals utilities are incredible, kind of surprising the level of access they provide aren't easily accessible in Windows by now.